# How to create Elasticsearch data stream template on a python's client?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

How can I make this index template PUT call on python's client?

An example of a working PUT request on Elastic console:

```
    PUT _index_template/ts_event_template
    {
      "index_patterns": [
        "ts-events"
      ],
      "data_stream": {},
      "template": {
        "settings": {
          "number_of_shards": 1,
          "number_of_replicas": 1,
          "index": {
            "lifecycle": {
              "name": "ts_policy_v1",
              "rollover_alias": "ts_events_alias"
            }
          }
        },
        "aliases": {
          "ts_events_alias": {}
        }
      }
    }
```

An example for the failing index template when using with the client put_template function:

```
resp = client.indices.put_template(
    name="datastream",
    body={
        "index_patterns": ["ts-events"],
        "data_stream": {},
        "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "index": {
              "lifecycle": {
                "name": "ts_policy_v1",
                "rollover_alias": "ts_events_alias"
              }
           }
         },
         "aliases": {
            "ts_events_alias": {}
         }
      }
   }
)
print(resp)
```

That raises a parsing error for the **data_stream** field.

How can I make this to work as a datastream index template?

Answer (score 0):

The old indices `put_template` is using the legacy index template version.

In order to use the latest index template you should use:

```
es_client.indices.put_index_template(name="index template name", body={template json here...})
```